# Black out screen like during a phone call

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I made an app that tracks the user's sleep over night using the accelerometer. However, this is pretty power consuming because accelerometers are not allowed to run under lock screen.

As an alternative, I'd like to disable the device's screen, just like it does during a phone call (when you touch the upper part, where your ear would be). I've seen the same behaviour in LINE, where you can do phone calls over a data connection.

I wonder how this is possible, since one surely cannot programmatically interact with the screen device. I've heard that for similar problems on other platforms (iOS), they simulate phone calls for this. Is something similar possible with Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "disable the device's screen" just change the page so that everything is black.

You could do this by: navigating to a separate page with nothing in it; putting an overlay over the current pages content to obscure it; or you could collapse the PhoneApplicationFrame.

With either of the first 2 options it'd be easy to return the user to the previous state when the page or overlay is tapped.

The native phone call application has access to the proximity sensor (and other settings we don't), hence the need to take a different approach.

Comment: I'm already doing this. But the touch screen still remains on and on cheaper/older displays, it's clearly visible in the dark (another problem).
Just out of curiosity, would it be possible to hack around this thru reflection (apart of certification problems)? I've seen ways of utilizing the video camera for flashlights, which also isn't possible with the official API.